# Use a reference to object properties

Tags: javascript

If I have an object like:

```
var myObj = { 'name,number,level': 'Mike,b1,0' };
```

How can I can reference to its properties?

How can I use :

```
myObj.name
myObj.number
myObj.level
```

Comment: you only have one key myObj['name,number,level']

Comment: To be clear, you want to convert `{ 'name,number,level': 'Mike,b1,0' }` to `{ 'name': 'Mike', 'number': 'b1', 'level': '0' }` ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you explain a little bit ? How can an object have arguments ? are you referring to properties ?

Comment: For those operations, your object should look like `var myObj = { 'name': 'Mike' ,'number' : 'b1' ,'level': 0};`

Comment: Yes, I want to separate the fields and use `{ 'name': 'Mike', 'number': 'b1', 'level': '0' }`.And I am refering to properties,sorry.

Comment: @ rajuGT: Defining it like that will result in a 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier(…)'

Comment: where are you getting the object from?

Comment: @George you can split key and values then make a new object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use square bracket notation: `myObj['name,number,level']` to get the value. If you want the individual pieces to be mapped (and you only have this key) you could do something like:

```
var newObj = {},
    values = myObj['name,number,level'].split(',');

newObj.name = values[0];
newObj.number = values[1];
newObj.level = values[2];
```

A more generic way to do it would be:

```
function convertToIndividualKeys(obj) {
  var key, keys, values, newObj = {};
  for(key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      keys = key.split(',');
      values = obj[key].split(',');
      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length && i < values.length; i++) {
        newObj[keys[i]] = values[i];
      }
    }
  }

  return newObj;
}

var myObj = { 'name,number,level': 'Mike,b1,0' };
myObj = convertToIndividualKeys(myObj);

// Now you can access it the way you would like
myObj.name // gives "Mike"
```

Notes:

With these conversions, the values will all be strings. The 0 from your example will actually be '0' so you may need to manually convert it to an integer depending on how you are using it.

This will overwrite other values if you have multiple keys i.e.`myObj = { 'name,number': 'A,1', 'name2,number': 'B,2' };` would likely turn into `{ name: 'A', name2: 'B', number: 2 }`

Comment: :I opened a new post if you are interested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747912/use-a-reference-to-many-entries-object-properties)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the initial key to find out the single keys , then use them to create a new object the way you want. Here is the sample code.

```js
var myObj = {
  'name,number,level': 'Mike,b1,0'
};
for (var i in myObj) {
  var keys = i;
  var value = myObj[i];
  keysArray = keys.split(",");
  valArray = value.split(",");

  var newObj = {};
  for (i = 0; i < keysArray.length; i++) {

    newObj[keysArray[i]] = valArray[i];

  }

  alert(newObj.name);
  alert(newObj.number);
  alert(newObj.level);
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up that this solution only works if there is only one key in the object. Only the last key/value pair in the object will be processed.