# Use a reference to many entries object properties

Tags: javascript

This is a continue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745906/use-a-reference-to-object-properties).

What If I have an object :

```
var myObj = [

{ 'name,number,level': 'Mike,b1,0' },
{ 'name,number,level': 'Rik',b2,0' },
{ 'name,number,level': 'Tom',b3,0'},
....
}
];
```

How can I use:

```
myObj.name
myObj.number
myObj.level
```

For example `myObj.name` should give all the names , or
`myObj.name[0]` will give me the first name.

Comment: To quote the old Irish saying, "if you want to get there, you shouldn't start from here"...

Comment: is it a question of how to apply the given answer?

Comment: why not keeping it as  var myObj  =[   [name: {a,b,c} , number: {1, 2, 3},]     ] etc ? . Duplication of keys can be avoided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to keep this answer more specific to the given example, you can expand on it by combining this with the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37746201/2660531) if needed. Note that this method will only work in IE 9 and above and should work in all other current browsers.

```js
var myObj = [
  { 'name,number,level': 'Mike,b1,0' },
  { 'name,number,level': 'Rik,b2,0' },
  { 'name,number,level': 'Tom,b3,0' }
];

myObj = myObj.reduce(function(newObj, currentItem) {
    var values = currentItem['name,number,level'].split(',');
    newObj.name.push(values[0]);
    newObj.number.push(values[1]);
    newObj.level.push(values[2]);
  
    return newObj;
  },
  {
    name: [],
    number: [],
    level: []
  });
                     

console.log('names:', myObj.name)
console.log('first name:', myObj.name[0]);
console.log('numbers:', myObj.number)
console.log('first number:', myObj.number[0]);
console.log('levels:', myObj.level)
console.log('first level:', myObj.level[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be building your object that way. You shouldn't even call it an object, it's a *list of objects*, where each object is composed of a **name**, **number** and **level**.

```
list_of_objects = [{
  name: "mike",
  number: "b1",
  level: 0
}, {
  name: "kevin",
  number: "b2",
  level: 1
}]

//Loop through your array
list_of_objects.forEach(function(myObj, index){
  console.log(myObj.name + " : " + myObj.number + " : " + myObj.level);
});

//Access the first person in your list
console.log(list_of_objects[0].name); //mike
```

Comment: :The problem is that I already have this object in this format.So , I want either to create a new object and then do something like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are committing a mistake, the proper way to do that is like this:

**Option 1:**

```
var myObj = 
[
    { 
      'name': 'Mike',
      'number': 'b1',
      'level': '0'
    },
    { 
      'name': 'Rik',
      'number': 'b2',
      'level': '0'
    }
];
```

You can access to the values:

```
myObj[0].name
myObj[0].number
myObj[0].level
```

**Option 2:**

Or you can do like this:

```
var myObj = 
{
    'name': ['Mike', 'Rik'],
    'number': ['b1', 'b2'],
    'level': ['0', '0']
};
```

You can access to the values:

```
myObj.name[0]
myObj.number[0]
myObj.level[0]
```

You can choose **option 1** or **option 2** depending in the way you want to arrange your data.

Comment: :The problem is that I already have this object in this format.So , I want either to create a new object and then do something like your answer.